# Handling NULL when using NOT EQUAL operator

Tags: mysql, null, comparison, equals

I have Table A which is joined with Table B "USING" column_1. I want the query to show all rows in Table A where the value in column_2 does not equal any of the values in column_2, column_3 or column_4 of the joined row in Table B.

So, I tried using:

```
WHERE
A.column_2 <> B.column_2 AND
A.column_2 <> B.column_3 AND
A.column_2 <> B.column_4
```

Now, if every cell in B.column_2, B.column_3 and B.column_4 has some value in it, the query check will work and it will list all rows in Table A where the value in A.column_2 has no match in Table B.

The issue happens if some of the cells in Table B have a NULL value. Then no results will be returned. This seems to be because MySQL considers the following to be FALSE:

```
23 <> NULL
```

... And since the query is looking for cases where all of the checks return TRUE, it returns nothing.

The following is a work-around that I employed by placing the Table B columns wrapped around with an IFNULL where the IFNULL value is 0. Essentially this converts all those NULL cells to 0... and therefore the NOT EQUAL check will correctly return TRUE when there are no matches and those rows in Table A will display. The code is like this:

```
WHERE
A.column_2 <> IFNULL(B.column_2, 0) AND
A.column_2 <> IFNULL(B.column_3, 0) AND
A.column_2 <> IFNULL(B.column_4, 0)
```

This seems to be a round-about way to handle this. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: you can use coalesce function

Comment: @Jordan ifnull() is pretty much the same as coalesce(), just limited to 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

YOU can also use the **<=>** Operator.

**see**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT 1 <> 1 , 1 <> 0 , 0 <> 0, 0 <> NULL , NULL <> 0 , 0 <=> NULL, NULL <=> 0, NULL <=> NULL;
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+
| 1 <> 1 | 1 <> 0 | 0 <> 0 | 0 <> NULL | NULL <> 0 | 0 <=> NULL | NULL <=> 0 | NULL <=> NULL |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+
|      0 |      1 |      0 |      NULL |      NULL |          0 |          0 |             1 |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: <=> is a null safe equasion operator. You would have to create quite a complicated where criteria with this operator to achieve the same output as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `not in` operator instead:

```
... WHERE A.column_2 NOT IN (B.column_2,B.column_3,B.column_4)
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! I use IN and NOT IN for other things. However, usually it's in a set of static values. I forget that a cell can be referenced in the same manner. The nice thing is that IN will work to check for the opposite, i.e. show me all the rows that do match. Kudos!

Comment: Then pls mark the answer as accepted to show other viewers of this topic that the question is now resolved!

Comment: I did. However, it won't show that I did until I earn 15 reputation points. (I'm still new here....)

Comment: Shadow, I tried it in my script and it didn't work. "IN" showed all the correct matches. However, "NOT IN" did not show the ones that didn't. Could NULL be having the same effect on NOT IN as it does on <> ?